# Neo4j/cypher - copy relationship labels to another

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have done a number of different queries but am trying to copy *all* the relationships between my two nodes `r` to `rn` (where there is a Rel_Office label) but for some reason only the final query here works. I'm using Neo4j Community 5.13.0.

*Doesn't work*

```
MATCH (c:Companies)-[r:Rel_Office]-(o:Companies) 
MATCH (n:Companies) WHERE c.CompanyID = X AND n.CompanyID = Y
MERGE (n)-[rn:Props]-(o) 
SET rn = properties(r)
```

*Doesn't work*

```
MATCH (c:Companies)-[r:Rel_Office]-(o:Companies) 
MATCH (n:Companies) WHERE c.CompanyID = X AND n.CompanyID = Y
MERGE (n)-[rn:Props]-(o) 
SET rn = r
```

*Does work but limited to one label!*

```
MATCH (c:Companies)-[r:Rel_Office]-(o:Companies) 
MATCH (n:Companies) WHERE c.CompanyID = 477 AND n.CompanyID = 9045
MERGE (n)-[rn:Rel_Office]-(o)
```

I suspect its something obvious, but please can someone explain how this should be working to do a full copy of all the labels/properties?

Comment: Query #3 has no `SET` clause. Did you accidentally omit that from the question? Otherwise, it would not copy anything at all from `r` to `rn`. Also, you seem to be misusing the term "label"; I think you mean "property"?

Comment: The Merge naturally creates the relationship with the single label ... it works but yes its not a copy as such. But why would these not work?

Comment: See my answer .

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that relationships always have 1 and only 1 type. You need to reconsider how to carry out your use case.

I also have a lot of observations.

1. `X` and `Y` are not defined, so queries 1 and 2 would fail anyway.
2. You are incorrectly using the term "label", which only applies to nodes (for example, `c` has the label `Companies`). Every relationship has **1 and only 1** "type".
3. The `SET` clause syntaxes you used are only for copying *properties*, not node labels or relationship types. In fact, you cannot change a relationship instance's type, so there is no way to do that in Cypher.
4. Your third query is missing a `SET` clause, which I assume was accidentally omitted from your question.
5. For better performance, filtering should always be done as soon as possible (like, right after the relevant `MATCH`).

   - Option 1: move the `c.CompanyID = 477` test immediately after `MATCH (c:Companies)-[r:Rel_Office]-(o:Companies)`.
   - Option 2, combine the 2 `MATCH` clauses, like this: `MATCH (c:Companies)-[r:Rel_Office]-(o:Companies), (n:Companies)`

Comment: I had forgotten about the 1 type only on a relationship. Which I feel is slightly odd considering you can have multiple on a node. I stripped my question back so X and Y are simply ints but thanks for that and also the performance suggestion as well. As it is I know that if a Rel_Office exists so also does a generic Rel so I will have to match on that and then create the other relationships as well. Its a shame you can't list all relationships between 2 points (where one matches) and then copy all the others - that is what I was aiming to achieve, Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be treated as "copy or duplicate all relationships from : Rel_Office into a new one called : Props.  Thus below query will work.

```
MATCH (c:Companies)-[r:Rel_Office]-(o:Companies)
MERGE (c)-[rn:Props]-(o)
SET rn = properties(r)
```

[image]

Comment: The question is a bit confusing, but he is actually trying to copy a second relationship type (`Rel_Office`) to `rn`, which already has the `Props` type. That is not possible.